# Parse elements from href tags

Tags: php, html, xpath

I need some help with my code. I want to parse each element from the streams tags but I cant find out how I could do this.

When I try this:

```
$streams_url = $xpath->query("//span[@id='streams'"]);
```

I will get something like this:

```
serverip page isn’t working

serverip is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

function getState($string)
{
  $ex = explode(" ",$string);
  return $ex[1];
}

$baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://myserverip/get-listing.php');

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$domdoc->recover=true;
@$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$i = 0;
$count = 0;
$streams_url = $xpath->query("//span[@id='streams'"]);
echo $streams_url;

$data = array();
>?
```

Here is the html data:

```
<a id="link1" href="http://myserverip/getlisting.php?channel=skyatlantic">http://myserverip/getlisting.php?channel=Sky Atlantic&id=108</a><br><br><a id="streams" href="rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyatlantic">Stream 1</a>
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
http://www.testserver.com/stream01
```

I want to parse each element from the streams tags.

Can you please show me how i could do this in PHP??

Comment: try PHPQuery https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery

Comment: I am not using PHPQuery, I want to use my own code as it is working fine but there is something that don't seen to work quite well. I have found out that I make a mistake. There is no span in `<a id="streams"` as it is a hyperlink so do you know how i could parse the element from the hyperlink to output the element?

Comment: where do you define $xpath?

Comment: Oh sorry I have forgot to include the `$xpath` to define it. When I try this `$xpath = new DOMXpath($sdoc); $streams_url = $xpath->query('//span[@id="streams"]');
echo $stream_url;` it is working fine but I have got the wrong tag which I don't have the span as I have only got the `<a id="streams` tag. Do you know how i can get the element from the `<a id` tag?

Comment: @trincot yeah I know that so how I can parse the element from the `(a)` with that id??

Comment: See my answer. With XPath, you would leave out the `span` in the path, but with `getElementById` it is more straightforward. NB: there is also a typo in your xpath: the closing square bracket is badly positioned.

Comment: @trincot ok thank you for your advise, so how I can use `getElementById` to parse the element from (a) tag as there is two hyperlink in my html code??  if you could post an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the `id` you are looking for, you don't actually need to use XPath. This will do the job:

```
$el = $domdoc->getElementById('streams');
$url = $el->getAttribute('href');
```

In comments you mention you have duplicate `id` values: this is invalid HTML. But you could process them as follows:

```
$streams_url = $xpath->query("//*[@id='streams']");
foreach($streams_url as $a) {
    $url[] = $a->getAttribute("href");
}
print_r($url); // array of href values
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I can see this one is works great `$url = $el->getAttribute('href');`, how i can parse each element from each streams tag as i have got two different hyderlink in my html page??

Comment: ID values must be unique in HTML. So how can you have more of them?

Comment: I have more of them using the same ID where you can see this: `<a id="streams" href="rtmp://www.testserver.com/stream1">Stream 1</a>`  `<a id="streams" href="rtmp://www.testserver.com/stream2">Stream 1</a>`..etc

Comment: Well, that conflicts with the HTML standard which says the [id value must be unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) in the whole document.