# Parsing the elements from one of these tags in arrays

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I need some help with my code. I have a problem with parsing the elements from the html tags, there are two different html tags I have in my html page which there are `<a id="link1"` and `<a id="streams"`.

When I try this:

```
$streams_url = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($streams_url as $a)
{
   $url[0] = $a->getAttribute("href");
   print_r($url);
}
```

I will get the full elements from the both html tags `<a id="link1"` and `<a id="streams"`.

Here is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=BBC One S East&id=101 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/bbc1 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=BBC Two&id=102) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/bbc2 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=ITV&id=103 )
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/itv1 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=Channel 4&id=104 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/channel4 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=Channel 5&id=105 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/channel5 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=Sky One&id=106 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyone ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=Sky Living&id=107 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyliving ) 
Array ( [0] => http://myserverip/get-listing.php?channels=Sky Atlantic&id=108 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyatlantic )
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
//error_reporting(0);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

function getState($string)
{
  $ex = explode(" ",$string);
  return $ex[1];
}
$baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://myserverip/get-listing.php');

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$domdoc->recover=true;
$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);

$streams_url = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($streams_url as $a)
{
   $url[0] = $a->getAttribute("href");
   print_r($url);
}
?>
```

What I want to achieve is I want to get the elements from the streams tags to make it show like this:

```
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/bbc1 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/bbc2 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/itv1 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/channel4 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/channel5 ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyone ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyliving ) 
Array ( [0] => rtmp://www.testserver.com/skyatlantic )
```

Could you please show me an example of what the best way I could use to parse the elements from the tag called `<a id="streams` while ignore the elements from the other tag??

Comment: I thought you already had the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900860/parse-elements-from-href-tags/37900992#37900992). Why don't you use that to only get those `a` with that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that `href` of stream will always begin with `rtmp://` you can use this (if you are looking for quick and easy solution):

```
foreach($streams_url as $a)
{
   $url[0] = $a->getAttribute("href");
   if($url[0][0]=='r') print_r($url);
}
```